# Why is a SPAN included in comments $created variable

Tags: theming

I noticed that SPAN tags are included when the $created variable is printed in comment.tpl.php

This seems to be true even if that variable has been preprocessed with format_date().  Why is this and is there anyway remove the span?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I am building a custom theme from scratch. No base theme.